# Validación de expresiones regulares en C#

Tags: c#, regex

Estoy tratando de obtener patron regex utilizando la siguiente placa modelos,

Ejemplo: (1) HKJ98C (2) HKJ98C. (3) HKJ988 (4) HKJ988.

Tengo ésto:

```
[^ A-Za-z0-9] +? \. {0,1}
```

Debo validar solo letras y números y puntos min 0 máximo 1, no deberá permitir otro tipo de símbolos o espacios.

Comment: Hola yandres95, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, que has probado hasta el momento y que es lo que no funciona como esperabas?. Si quieres, para hacer pruebas y preguntar algo mas concreto, puedes hacer pruebas [aqui](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Debo validar placas que consten de 3 LETRAS SEGUIDA DE DOS NUMEROS Y UNA LETRA O NUMERO AL FIN Y EN OCASIONES PUNTO AL FINAL. Y NO DEBE PERMITIR INGRESAR ESPACIOS NI SIMBOLOS ESPECIALES.

Comment: Solo me está permitiendo  letras & números y validando el NO ingreso de simbolos y caracteres especiales pero no me valida el punto al final cuando digito. El punto al final es aveces min 0 max 1.

Comment: Cómo sugerencia: Las mayúsculas sostenidas son innecesarias. Da la impresión que gritas a los demás. Sobre tu pregunta, no hay código C# en ella y no sabemos qué te falla de la expresión que nos compartes

Answer (score 0):

esta expresión cumple con tus requisitos:

```
[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z0-9]{1}[.]*
```

La puedes ver [aquí](https://regexr.com/4n92r) dónde he añadido tus 4 modelos de placa en medio de texto aleatorio.

Comment: Gracias! Esto funciono para mí: ^[A-Za-z0-9]{6}\.{0,1}$

Comment: Yandres95, la expresión que indicas en tu comentario no cumple con lo que indicas ya que acepta cualquier combinación entre números y letras. La expresión de esta respuesta es la adecuada por garantiza que las primeras 3 sean letras luego 2 dígitos y finalmente un dígito o letra ( el {1} final se pueda sacar pero así se da más claridad a lo que secquiere)